# Add list to Excel column

Tags: python, excel, loops, pandas, fasta

I have two files:

- 1 file is a fasta file containing sequence names and their sequences.
- the other file is an excel file, it has one 'Hcolumn' of the sequence names and an empty column next it with the header 'Hsequence' and one 'Kcolumn' of sequence names and an empty column next to it with the header 'Ksequence'.

I want to loop through both files, if a sequence name in the fasta file is also in either the 'Hcolumn' or 'Kcolumn', then add the sequence to the corresponding sequence column in the excel file, which is either the 'Hsequence' or the 'Ksequence' column. 
My idea here is to get the location of the vh value, and add  its seq value to the cell on  its right (the next row).

**Update with examples**

fasta file (ignoring the > sign):

```
headerA
AAAGGCCT
headerB
ATCCTTTG
headerC
GGGGTCCCAAT
```

excel sheet

```
Hcolumn   Hsequence     Kcolumn    Ksequence 
headerA                 headerB
headerC                 headerE
headerD                 headerF
```

desired outcome:

```
Hcolumn   Hsequence     Kcolumn    Ksequence 
headerA   AAAGGCCT      headerB    ATCCTTTG
headerC   GGGGTCCCAAT   headerE
headerD                 headerF
```

my new code: (my code below only deals with one column, i don't yet know how to say if it's in columnA OR in columnB)

```
for line in f:         
    seq = f.readline()
    for vh in data["Hcolumn"]:
        vh = vh.rstrip()
        if (title in vh): 
            #print(">"+title, seq)
            data["HSequence"]=data["Hcolumn"].apply(lambda vh: seq)

        else:
            data["HSequence"]=data["Hcolumn"].apply(lambda vh: '')
            break               
return data.to_csv('Fullseqfile.txt', sep='\t')
```

the sequence column returned null, can someone help
thanks

Comment: what is data and what does .apply() do?

Comment: @jcfollower  data is the excel sheet.  with  .appy() i'm trying to say if the title from the file is in Hcolumn, then add the next line from the file to Hsequence column

Comment: `.apply(lambda vh: seq)` confuses me.  My understanding is that lambda's should looks something like this ... `lambda x: 2*x`, which means "take x and return its double".  It looks like your lambdas return `seq` and `''` respectively, no matter what the input is.

Comment: @jcfollower so how should i write it so that the program gives seq to 'Hsequence' column when 'Hcolumn' contains the title from fasta file? thanks!

Comment: What library are you using for the excel.  Is there an `import` statement for it at the top of the file?

Comment: @jcfollower  i'm using pandas , i use pd.read_excel()   for the excel table and pd.read_csv() for the fasta file.

Comment: OK, sorry, I don't know anything about pandas.  You may want to add that to the tags for your question.

Comment: @jcfollower no problem, so do you know how to achieve what i'm trying to do by just python and not pandas? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: !cat data/question1/file.fasta
headerA
AAAGGCCT
headerB
ATCCTTTG
headerC
GGGGTCCCAAT

In [3]: xls=pd.read_excel('file.xls')

In [4]: xls
Out[4]: 
   Hcolumn  Hsequence  Kcolumn  Ksequence
0  headerA        NaN  headerB        NaN
1  headerC        NaN  headerE        NaN
2  headerD        NaN  headerF        NaN

In [5]: fh = open('file.fasta')
   ...: fasta_dic={}
   ...: for line in fh:
   ...:     if line.startswith('h'):
   ...:         seq_header = line.strip('\n')
   ...:         fasta_dic[seq_header] = ''
   ...:     else:
   ...:         fasta_dic[seq_header] = line.strip('\n')
   ...:         

In [6]: def fill_seq(x):
   ...:     if x in fasta_dic.keys():
   ...:         return fasta_dic[x]
   ...:     else:
   ...:         return ''
   ...:     

In [7]: xls['Hsequence'] = xls['Hcolumn'].apply(fill_seq)
   ...: xls['Ksequence'] = xls['Kcolumn'].apply(fill_seq)
   ...: 

In [8]: xls
Out[8]: 
   Hcolumn    Hsequence  Kcolumn Ksequence
0  headerA     AAAGGCCT  headerB  ATCCTTTG
1  headerC  GGGGTCCCAAT  headerE          
2  headerD               headerF
```

1. Builds a dictionary `fasta_dic` with the sequences names as key and the sequences as value.
2. The function `fill_seq`checks if the input `x` it's in the dictionary you defined before, if it finds the value it will return the sequence.
3. You apply the function `fill_seq` to the H/K sequence columns using the values from H/K sequence as input.

After this you can keep working with your dataframe or export it to a xls file.

Answer (score 1):

This a quick attempt at giving you some ideas ...

```
FASTA = [
    'headerA',
    'AAAGGCCT',
    'headerB',
    'ATCCTTTG',
    'headerC',
    'GGGGTCCCAAT',
]


EXCEL = {
    'Hcolumn': ['headerA', 'headerC', 'headerD'],
    'Hsequence': {},
    'Kcolumn': ['headerB', 'headerE', 'headerF'],
    'Ksequence': {},
}

for index in range(0, len(FASTA), 2):
    value = FASTA[index]
    column = EXCEL['Hcolumn']
    # print index, value, column
    if value in EXCEL['Hcolumn']:
        position = column.index(value)
        EXCEL['Hsequence'][position] = FASTA[index+1]

for item in EXCEL.iteritems():
    print item

========================

('Hcolumn', ['headerA', 'headerC', 'headerD'])
('Kcolumn', ['headerB', 'headerE', 'headerF'])
('Hsequence', {0: 'AAAGGCCT', 1: 'GGGGTCCCAAT'})
('Ksequence', {})
```